# TestFlight Beta only allowing 30 days

Tags: ios, testflight

On TestFlight you can only allow users to test apps for 30 days. So you will have to upload a new build every 30 days?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this indeed the case. Any builds within the *Prerelease* section within iTunes Connect are only valid for 30 days. So, after a build expires and you want your users to be able to keep on testing you'll have to upload a new build.

This is also stated on the [Testflight website](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/):

> The beta period lasts for 30 days, starting on the day it is released
>   to testers. In TestFlight, the number of days remaining appears below
>   the Open button for each app.

[image]

Note that in normal circumstances, 30 days is more than enough for any beta testing phase....

Answer (score 1):

As of November 13. 2015. there are some changes occurred in iTunesConnect:

> To make your TestFlight experience even better,
>   we’ve made some significant changes. You can now invite up to 2000
>   external testers and up to 25 internal testers per app. You can also
>   test up to 100 apps at the same time for up to 60 days, and submit up
>   to 6 updates per day to your external testers.

So, right now the beta period lasts for 60 days ( starting on the day it is released to testers).